# Traversing a tree in haskell?

Tags: haskell

Im having trouble writing a function in haskell that produces a copy of its argument in which each node’s value has been decreased by 1. My main question is how to traverse recursively in haskell given this problem. Heres what im given:

```
data ITree = IEmpty
              | INode Int ITree ITree   
    deriving (Eq, Show)

-- An example of a tree
t1 :: ITree
t1 = INode 2 (INode 1 (INode 4 IEmpty IEmpty)
                      (INode 5 IEmpty IEmpty))
             (INode 7 IEmpty IEmpty)
```

Heres my attempt:

```
decITree :: ITree -> ITree
decITree IEmpty = undefined
decITree (INode n left right) = (n-1) ++ (decITree left) ++ (decITree right)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `INode n left right` you here aim to return, based on the use of `(++)` a list of elements. But the types do not match anyway, since `n-1` is an `Int` not a list.

If you want to decrement the items in a tree, then you should for each `ITree` also *return* an `ITree`. So the skeleton should look like:

```
decITree :: ITree -> ITree
decITree IEmpty = … -- (some ITree)
decITree (INode n left right) = … -- (some ITree)
```

As for an `IEmpty`, there is only one sensical value to return: an `IEmpty` as well, since there is nothing to decrement.

For an `INode`, we can return an `INode with a decremented value`(n-1)` as value, and we need to recurse on the children of the node:

```
decITree :: ITree -> ITree
decITree IEmpty = IEmpty
decITree (INode n left right) = INode (n-1) (decITree left) (decITree right)
```

The above is a special sort of *mapping*. Usually it is better to work with more generic functions. We can for example define an [*abstract data type* [haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Abstract_data_type), and by using the [**`DeriveFunctor`** extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-DeriveFunctor), we can let the compiler do the work for us:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data Tree a = Empty
             | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
    deriving (Eq, Show, Functor)
```

Then decrementing the elements of the tree is just:

```
decTree :: Tree Int -> Tree Int
decTree = fmap pred
```

Comment: the misuse of the term "abstract data type" (even with the link) is bound to cause grave confusion for many a newbie reader henceforth. downvoted until fixed.